# How to add attachment without uploading?

Tags: attachments

When save post, I made dir in wp_uploads_dir, and copied 2 files and one folder in this dir. Now I want to do the WP_insert_attatchment process to make the 2 files as attachements. How can I do it?

Edit: I inset_attatchement by directly using their URL. Now they show up in Media Libray, but I can't see whether the attachment_id is recorded or not. Which table in database can I go to find it?

Comment: I doubt if you can do that. An attachment is created when you use the uploader to add files. Manually added files may be used with the actual URLs but I'm not aware if you can add them as attachment through WP. :-|

Comment: I'm trying to use the URLs, haven't got it working yet. Not sure if it's my code wrong or it's wp reject.

Comment: success. it can be added by URL. I can see the files in Media Library. Only problem is -- I can't find attachment_id in any dababase tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the local path to add an attachment:

```
// add the file to the media library
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/png' // the MIME type
,   'post_title'     => 'Attachment title'
);

// Adds the file to the media library and generates the thumbnails.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $path ); // PATH!
```

Comment: I added and edited my question. Now the problem is -- I want to comfirm that I added it at correct place. I want to see which database table the attachment_id is stored.

Comment: Attachments are stored in the regular posts table, they are just a post type. `wp_get_attachment_image( $attach_id );` will return an image element and `wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attach_id );` the URL.

Comment: I don't need the id. I just want to see where it is in the database. I checked in phpadmin, I don't see anywhere in the database there's a key about attachment. Which table should I look for it?

Comment: The `posts` table. There is a column named `post_type`. Attachment are of the post type … well … `attachment`. :) Try `SELECT * FROM \`wp_posts\` WHERE post_type = 'attachment'` to get the attachments only.

Comment: Thanks, got it! I went to postmeta table straight, missed it :-)